# Initializing variable as equal to another without having future changes to the former affect the latter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know people mostly refer to two-way binding when it comes to variables displayed in the HTML, but I keep running into this same problem and realized there is something fundamental about Angular that I'm not understanding.

To set up this question, I am currently developing an RPG browser game. I want each character to have baseStats which are represented as:

```
'baseStats' : {
    'defense' : 5,
    'strength' : 3,
    'speed' : 7
}
```

but during the course of the battle, they may be 'buffed' or 'debuffed', so I want to be able to track those changes without permanently changing the characters stats, so baseStats exists to preserve the 'original' state of the stats.

```
vm.restoreAll = function() {
  angular.forEach(vm.activeAllies, function(ally) {
    ally.stats.defense = ally.baseStats.defense;
    ally.stats.strength = ally.baseStats.strength;
    ally.stats.strength = ally.baseStats.speed;
  });
};
```

This works exactly as I intend it to. Each of these stats is reset to the baseStat

```
vm.restoreAll = function() {
  angular.forEach(vm.activeAllies, function(ally) {
     ally.stats = ally.baseStats;
  });
}
```

This is obviously more readable and terse, but unfortunately if I make changes to ally.stats from elsewhere in the application, those changes affect the baseStats as well. I'm confused why this would be as they seem to be effectively the same exact thing.

Comment: sounds like you want to use angular.copy() https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy The example on that page is showing pretty much what you are asking

Comment: This does give me the intended result... thanks! But I am still confused why Angular seems to behave in two different ways in seemingly syntactically identical situations.

Comment: because `ally.stats` is just a reference to `ally.baseStats`. It isn't a copy, which is why angular.copy() exists

Comment: I see. So ally.baseStats.strength would actually pass the value if it contains a value but if it contains an object it would only pass the reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not really specific to Angular but Javascript in general. When you pass object values around to different variables you are not passing the actual object value but just a reference to the object. So the object value itself only exists in one place in memory and each variable holds a reference to that location.

This blog post explains further: http://nsono.net/javascript-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/

As the other comments already explain using Angular's copy function will cause an entire new object to be created and stored in memory and fix your issue.

There are various non-Angular ways of cloning objects as well, some described here: http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/

Probably the most concise: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`